# How can force a bash script to execute in www, and not executing in filesystem/*?

Tags: bash, filesystem, execute-command

I have some `.sh` bash scripts which creates some directories, downloads some sourcefiles via SVN and so on.

The scripts works every well, but it annoys me that they are performing the action in 
`filesystem/*`, not in `wwww`. If they create a directory like `/data`, it is created as `filesystem/data`, not `www/path/data`.

I have tried running the scripts from within subdirectories, eg

```
wwww/install/sh
```

but all the action is still performed in `filesystem/*`. I have also tried running with `./`, no luck.

I am always able to copy the generated file structure from `filesystem/` to `www`, but I would really like to know how I can force bash to execute where it is.

There is no hardcoded links pointing to filesystem, one of the .sh files looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /
mkdir data
cd /data
svn checkout <path to svn> mb32
cd mb32 
mv www/htaccess.txt www/.htaccess
INSTALL_PATH=`pwd`
INSTALL_PATH=$INSTALL_PATH"/"
to_replace="#php_value auto_prepend_file"
replace_by="php_value auto_prepend_file"
eval sed -i \'s/$to_replace/$replace_by/\' www/.htaccess
to_replace="/my/root/path/"
replace_by=$INSTALL_PATH
args="-i 's|$to_replace|$replace_by|' www/.htaccess"
eval sed $args
cp www/.htaccess ImageServer/
eval sed -i 's/app.server.php/image.server.php/g' ImageServer/.htaccess
echo "Changing permissions to configuration and log..."
sudo chmod -R 775 configuration
sudo chmod -R 775 log
echo "Done"
```

When it is runned from terminal, for example from `www/a/test`, it insists to create `filesystem/data` and download to `filesystem/data/mb32`. I would like it to download to `www/install/data` etc. I am obviously missing some very simple and basic.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want. What do you mean by `filesystem/*`? What exactly you have to copy, sources checkouted by svn?  If it is not a problem, could you please paste all your script. You can replace all path and names in `path1` and `name1` if worried about it.

Comment: @c0rp I agree, very poor explained :( Thank you for commenting! Have updated with the full source of one of the .sh files. The "installation" goes well, and I can just copy the files afterwards, but how could I - if possible - force it to execute in www?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right at the top:
`cd /` changes to the root directory. Also, the slash in line 4 needs to be removed.

Comment: Gee, I **knew** it was something completely simple and obvious. Translated it in my head as "one dir back", have starred at it too long I guess. How could I miss that :( Thank you.